# OpenVPN clients traffic

Tags: openvpn, ubuntu-12.04

How can I see or even control a client cert traffic in OpenVPN? Is it possible? I'm programming a Client Control Web App and I find nothing about it. Is there any script or commands for that? In OpenVPN Access Server I've seen such thing.

Edit: To be clear I want users traffic usage.

Comment: What do you mean by "control a client cert traffic"? Are you looking for something as simple as a packet capture? Or perhaps just watching the OpenVPN log?

Comment: @EEAA What I mean is I want to see a user traffic usage.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the clarification. Please edit your question and include that information.

Comment: You ask many question about openvpn and each time you say `in OpenVPN Access Server I've seen such thing`. Maybe, one day, you should consider bying a license for it...

Comment: @user2196728 I prefer not spending money for license and because of that I'm developing an access server for myself. And your comment is not related to my question.

Comment: For sure i guess you don't want to spend money, i understand that...but why rewriting something that already exists ? except if your goal is to provide a **free** openvpn access server alternative, and make it **publicly** available under **GNU licence** ;) To come back to your question, i would suggest to parse iptables logs !

Comment: @user2196728 Yes, it's a free openvpn access server and if I can solve some problems I will publish the software on GitHub under GNU licence. But can you help me about this question?

Comment: Great ! i will be a user of your soft so ! i've already suggested you to parse iptables logs to display client traffic, and to control client traffic you could dynamically update iptables rules also.

Comment: Also look at scripting hooks.  OpenVPN passes some data to the scripting hooks, which you can have your scripts captures/store.  You might for example want need to have the `down-pre` hook connect to the management interface and grab the status for that client.

Comment: @Zoredache Thanks, I didn't know I can use telnet for OpenVPN. Please make your comment as a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think after searching throw internet I finally found my proper answer. I can enable management in my `config` file and use `telnet` to connect to management. Then I can use `status` command to print log for connected users. In there I can see byes received and sent by connected users. And I think OpenVPN has a database some where for storing user status logs!

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to step down to IP based user identification, you can expect openvpn to reassign the same VPN-IP for a user's lifetime. See assigned IPs in ipp.txt (/etc/openvpn/servers/VPN/logs, path may vary). Then, check if traffic passes through linux kernel. It might stay within the OpenVPN daemon, not sure about that. tcpdump and see what happens. If it passes through the linux kernel, normal IP accounting would work well (MRTG et al). If it does stay in the daemon, openvpn-status.log contains the external IPs of the currently connected users. Correlating that with MRTG data may be a tough exercise, though. So check if there's any config option for openvpn to force traffic through the kernel.

You're using a Linux server, right?

Comment: Yes, an ubuntu server